# How does Reputation Tile swapping work?

Tags: eclipse

After combat has finished and you have drawn between 1 and 5 Reputation Tiles, can you exchange any Reputation Tiles you have on your Reputation Track for any that you draw from the bag? So if I have a space with a 1 Reputation tile and I draw a 4 from the bag can I swap the 1 for the 4? And what happens to the 1 - does it go back in the bag or into a discard pile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the rulebook](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/732184/eclipse-rules-in-pdf-format), page 21, emphasis mine:

> You may not draw more than five tiles. Choose one of the tiles and place it face down on your Reputation Track. Put the rest of the tiles back in the bag. **If the track is full, you may return any of your Reputation Tiles (including the one you just drew or one from the track) in the bag.** The tiles are drawn in the order the play­ers entered the hex, so that the player who first entered the hex will draw all his tiles first.

So you can put the 1 back in the bag *if your reputation track is full* to free a space to place the 4.